# SQL - Linked Server with Excel imports values as NULL

Tags: excel, ssms, linked-server

I have been successfully using a linked server with SQL Server Management Studio importing a file from Excel which has four columns.

The Excel document looks like (no TOOL means blank cell, rows 6-199)

```
TDS    HOLDER    TOOL
1        3       1187
2        4       09812
3        5       9082
4        2       ----
5        76      ----
6        9       
7        1
.        .
.        .
.        .
200      18     CT-2989
201      98     CT-9871
```

When I import it as is, it will grab the cells with the numbers at the top, cells that contain `------` and then when it gets to the cells which are blank it will then print `NULL` for the rest of the data, which is incorrect.

When I alter my Excel document so that the 'CT' values are at the top, it will grab all of the proper CT and TL values in column 3.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the SQl Server Import and Export wizard. It uses the data in the top few rows of the spreadsheet to decide on the data types in each column. When your Tools column has numbers at the top the wizard decides the data type of the column is float. When the column had "CT-2989" at the top it chooses a char type. Once it has chosen the float type it will ignore CT-2989 because it isn't convertable to a floating point number. The simplest solution to the problem it to arrange your Excel spreadsheet with a dummy row at the very top which gives the wizard the proper types for each column. For example, make the first data cell in the Tools column "abcdefg", assuming the rest of the data in that column consists of up to 7 alphanumeric characters. Once your data has imported into SSMS, delete the dummy row.

If you go to the "Review DataType Mapping" page of the wizard it will show that the Tools column has been detected as containing float data when the numeric data is at the top of the spreadsheet. Note that the even if the destination type for the Tools column is nvarchar, the wizard makes it's own decisions regarding source type.

There are other solutions using openrowset() and SSIS, but this one is quick and simple.

Comment: I don't think this is the *quite* the problem because the OP says values of `----` *are* being returned successfully. (This is presumably a string.) Perhaps it's just a field length problem. Even if it is the problem, inserting dummy rows into data is not a good idea in the long term.

Comment: It's not the wizard its the Excel driver. This behaviour is shown in any tool using the Excel driver. I suggest you also look up the `IMEX` setting which you can add to your connection string to assist.

Comment: When I tested the OP's table the '----' came in as NULL. I agree my solution isn't a long term one which is why  describe it as quick and simple to get the OP over a hump. And yes, the Excel driver is the real culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Here the problem is with OLEDB which is unable to handel mixed data(numbers + text) so there is no solution only a few hacks some of them already mentioned above I just want to add a few more:-

1) In excel sheet Keep the data consistent and maintain distinct coloumns for each depending upon its data type e.g. text,numeric or whole numbers, fractional numbers etc.

2) Ok before importing it break down the sheet in multiple sheets based on its datatype so that OLEDB won't get confiused.

3) Import the excel sheet in MS Access so that it all the data would get a data type then import it into SQL this would handle NULL too very wisely.

Answer (score 0):

Save the worksheet as .CSV and import as a flat file from task, when reviewing the data, unchecked the Datatypes indicator.